Angular- Type ScrollingModule does not have 'ɵmod' property
In angular 11 i am facing error when i added primeng in package.json.

"@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.6",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.6",
"@angular/platform-server": "~11.0.6",
"@angular/router": "~11.0.6",
"@fullcalendar/angular": "4.3.1",
"@fullcalendar/core": "4.3.1",
"@fullcalendar/daygrid": "4.3.0",
"@fullcalendar/interaction": "4.3.0",
"@grapecity/wijmo.angular2.all": "^5.20211.794",
"@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.2.6",
"@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
"amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^6.3.13",
"angular2-text-mask": "9.0.0",
"aspnet-prerendering": "3.0.1",
"bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
"core-js": "^3.3.3",
"font-awesome": "4.7.0",
"jquery": "^3.7.0",
"ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
"oidc-client": "^1.9.1",
"popper.js": "^1.16.0",
"powerbi-client": "^2.22.3",
"primeicons": "2.0.0",
"primeng": "8.1.1",
"roboto-fontface": "0.10.0",
"rxjs": "~6.6.0",
"tslib": "1.10.0",
"zone.js": "~0.10.2"


Seems like compatibility version issue. AFAIK PrimeNG major version is the same as Angular major version. Try updating PrimeNG to version 11.
